# Is there a way for google sheets to show me a spreadsheet according to a value?

Tags: google-sheets

I have this spreadsheet, it basically resembles a calendar. I'm looking for a way to make it more user friendly. My idea was to have a dropdown for the month and that according to the value (november, december, etc), to show me that specific calendar. [Here's an example of how I picture it :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcBXX.png)
I have an idea of what I could do but I start trying and won't get anywhere.
Alsoooo, if you had any ideas on how I could make it better, please feel free to share!!

Thank you!

tried with xlookup but because i don't know from where specifically to bring the information from, I don't know. I just want the calendar and to put information in it